# Changing one child from one node to the other for Firebase in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here's my database structure :

```
users
   user1
      nodeA
        nodeToBeMoved
            content : content1
            date : date1
   user2
      nodeB
```

I'm looking to move the "nodeToBeMoved" from node A to node B, I tried to put the content1 and date1 into the variable "value" and then, delete the "nodeToBeMoved", and then add the variables to node B. But for some reason my app is crashing. Here's my code :

```
self.ref.child("users").child(user1).child(nodeA).child(nodeToBeMoved).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let value = snapshot.valueInExportFormat() as AnyObject
            self.ref.child(users).child(user1).child(nodeA).child(nodeToBeMoved).removeValue()
            self.ref.child(users).child(user2).child(nodeB).child(nodeToBeMoved).child(content).setValue(value["content"] as Any)
            self.ref.child(users).child(user2).child(nodeB).child(nodeToBeMoved).child(date).setValue(value["date"] as Any)



        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

I believe I have a problem with the variable type. Can someone help me solve this ? And also this is my method, but if you know a better way to do it, feel free to say it.

Comment: What error are you getting with the crash?

Comment: fatal error: attempt to bridge an implicitly unwrapped optional containing nil

Comment: Yes the good old unexpected found nil. Please search more on this error here. Lots of answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `

```
self.ref.child("users").child(user1).child(nodeA).child(nodeToBeMoved).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as NSdictionnary
         if let actualvalue = value {
         self.ref.child(users).child(user1).child(nodeA).child(nodeToBeMoved).removeValue()
        self.ref.child(users).child(user2).child(nodeB).child(nodeToBeMoved).child(content).setValue(actualvalue["content"] as Any)
        self.ref.child(users).child(user2).child(nodeB).child(nodeToBeMoved).child(date).setValue(actualvalue["date"] as Any)

        }




    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```